# Tie a bash script to the ssh command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Is there any way to edit the ssh command in such way that 'ssh hostname' runs a bash script first before its standard function

Edit: Note that the ssh command's name stays the same, without adding anything to it.

Comment: Where should the "command" run? On the local machine? Or, on the remote host?

Comment: please edit your Q to show us how what you require is different that typical `ssh` remote command invocation, i.e. `ssh user@host '/bin/ls -l ; cd /home/user ; /bin/ls -l` etc.... Good luck.

Comment: As the script must run before, it can only run locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shell [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html). In your case:

```
alias ssh="echo 'hi'; ssh "
```

From now on, when you type `ssh` in the terminal, the shell will expand the alias.
In a shell script, you would need `shopt -s expand_aliases` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProxyCommand](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/).

Add to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostname
    ProxyCommand /path/to/bash-script
```